# Can I save flour dredge used for raw chicken for a later batch?

Tags: food-safety, flour, storage, raw-meat

What if I have like 50 pieces of chicken and I only fry 25 but I have 25 left would it be ok to use the same flour considering it’s the same batch of chicken

Answer (score 0):

Yes - though since it's come in contact with chicken and picked up chicken juices and bacteria, treat it like the raw chicken, store it in the fridge and use within the next day if possible.

A similar question, [Saving seasoned flour used for dredging chicken](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43174/saving-seasoned-flour-used-for-dredging-chicken) , has a couple more answers as well - none suggesting refrigeration.